# Preallocating 2D arrays in a Numba class

Tags: python-3.x, performance, type-conversion, declaration, numba

I am working on a class speedup with Numba. When you want to use Numba inside classes you have to define/preallocate your class variables. In this respect **my issue is declaring a 2D array before the** `jitclass`. The following MWE directly shows my issue:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import int32, float32
from numba.experimental import jitclass          # import the decorator

spec = [
    ('value', int32),               # a simple scalar field
    ('array', float32[:]),          # an array field
    ('foo_matrix',int32[:,:]),
]


@jitclass(spec)
class Bag(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.array = np.zeros(value)
        self.foo_matrix = np.zeros((value, value))

    @property
    def size(self):
        return self.array.size

    def increment(self, val):
        for i in range(self.size):
            self.array[i] = val
        return self.array

my_class = Bag(3)
```

When I execute this code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/acer/codici/tech/numba_prototype.py", line 38, in <module>
    my_class = Bag(3)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/experimental/jitclass/base.py", line 122, in __call__
    return cls._ctor(*bind.args[1:], **bind.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 414, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 357, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Internal error at <numba.core.typeinfer.CallConstraint object at 0x7fc6d4945c40>.
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)
Can only insert float* at [4] in {i8*, i8*, i64, i64, float*, [1 x i64], [1 x i64]}: got double*

File "numba_prototype.py", line 19:
    def __init__(self, value):
        <source elided>
        self.value = value
        self.array = np.zeros(value)
        ^

During: lowering "(self).array = $14call_method.5" at /home/acer/codici/tech/numba_prototype.py (19)
During: resolving callee type: jitclass.Bag#7fc6d5a2afa0<value:int32,array:array(float32, 1d, A),foo_matrix:array(int32, 2d, A)>
During: typing of call at <string> (3)

Enable logging at debug level for details.

File "<string>", line 3:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

which is related to the declaration of the matrix `foo_matrix`.

Concerning the types definition I followed [this](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.12/tutorial_numpy_and_numba.html).

Of course if I comment out the lines about array declaration and population the code works fine.
How should I modify/do the declaration of the matrix with respect to a jitclass object?

**EDIT**: inside the class, I have changed the declaration of foo_matrix from `np.zeros([value, value])` to `np.zeros((value, value))` since defining a numpy array using a list instead of a tuple may be a source of error for numba functions. However the problem persists even with this modification.

Comment: "inside the class, I have changed the declaration of foo_matrix from np.zeros([value, value]) to np.zeros((value, value)" **those aren't declarations**. Python doesn't really *have* variable declarations, unless you are talking about *type hints*, so you really need to be more precise about exactly what you are talking about. If you are getting an error, *post the error message*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am writing the error I get but concerning the declaration that's the main point. I am using Numba, for this reason you have to declare the type of the variables before using, just like C.

Comment: You are declaring `foo_matrix` as integer, but you are assigning a floating point array to it, as the error message says.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that in the zeros array and matrix there is no the type specification i.e. : `self.array = np.zeros(value, dtype=np.float32)`.

The working code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import int32, float32
from numba.experimental import jitclass      

spec = [
    ('value', int32),               
    ('array', float32[:]),          
    ('foo_matrix',int32[:,:]),
]


@jitclass(spec)
class Bag(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.array = np.zeros(value, dtype=np.float32)
        self.foo_matrix = np.zeros((value, value), dtype=np.int32)
        alice = value +1 
        bob = np.sum(self.array)

    @property
    def size(self):
        return self.array.size

    def increment(self, val):
        for i in range(self.size):
            self.array[i] = val
        return self.array





my_class = Bag(3)
```